# Jquery Change Event (or URL location) not functioning on iPhone (possibly mobile)

Tags: jquery, ios, onchange

I have a piece of jquery code that is meant to take the value of the option selected and change the url. This works in all the PC browsers I try but not the iPhone. I do not have a mac to troubleshoot with or an android, so I'm not sure how limited the problem is. Right now, nothing seems to happen on iOS on select change.

HTML

```
<select class="search-cat" name="search-cat">
  <option value="https://www.google.com/all/" selected>All</option>
  <option value="https://www.google.com/cat-1/">Category 1</option>
  <option value="https://www.google.com/cat-2/">Category 2</option>
</select>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function(){
  $('select.search-cat').on('change', function () {
      var url = $(this).val();
      if (url) { 
          window.location = url;
      }
      return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Try to assign `window.location.href` as well, and what's with the `return` statement?

Comment: That doesn't seem to have an effect. I have a feeling this issue has something to do with iOS and on change events because I've tried a simple alert on change and got nothing. It could be an issue with both on change and window.location in iOS too.

Comment: I've also tried changing "change" to "blur" with no luck.

Comment: You may remove this question. As the problem is actually not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `location.href`.

```js
$(function(){
  $('select.search-cat').on('change', function () {
      var url = $(this).val();
      if (url) { 
          location.href = url;
      }
      return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="search-cat" name="search-cat">
  <option value="https://www.google.com/all/" selected>All</option>
  <option value="https://www.google.com/cat-1/">Category 1</option>
  <option value="https://www.google.com/cat-2/">Category 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you really sure that this would address the problem? Until your solution genuinely addresses the issue, you should not post an answer. Use comments to request clarification instead.

Comment: I wonder if I have a caching issue with my iphone... I'll check

Comment: That was it. It was a caching issue. I changed the on change to an on blur and cleared the cache.

Comment: @Chaska -- you may remove your answer as it was actually not an issue which was solved by your solution.